# .htaccess non www to www with exception for sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I currently have a htaccess which rewrites all non www urls to www url.
However now i am integrating CDN with multiple subdomains but I want to exclude those subdomains to have www into it.

subdomains to exclude

`static.pc-helpforum.be`

`img.pc-helpforum.be`

`avatarts.pc-helpforum.be`

I have now tried this, but i'm not sure if its ok, please advise:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.pc-helpforum\.be$|^static\.pc-helpforum\.be$|^img\.pc-helpforum\.be$|^avatars\.pc-helpforum\.be$)`

`RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pc-helpforum.be/$1 [R=301,L]`

`RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 [L]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admincp/|modcp/|cron|vbseo_sitemap)`

`RewriteRule ^((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images)/`

`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]`

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
Karel

Answer (score 0):

Add this above your other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example\.com$
```

Comment: instead of multiple, just write one per line for those 3 sub domains

Comment: So this should be correct then?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.pc-helpforum\.be$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.pc-helpforum\.be$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^img\.pc-helpforum\.be$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^avatars\.pc-helpforum\.be$

Comment: doesn't display nicely in comments, but just try it.  You'll know right away and you can comment or change immediately after.  I've never chained them together like you did, just had one rule per line, and seem to work but they do take trial/error at times.  I notice sometimes the order that you add the rules affects the outcome so I have to "play" with that at times as well.  If you're editing httpd.conf or conf file don't forget to "reload" your web server to apply settings.  If .htaccess it'll likely be immediate.